# EntityFramework 5.0 Variables Data Annotations

Tags: data-annotations, entity-framework-5

I am using a DisplayText loading data from Database example:
Resume of code:

```
public class AtributosInModels : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    string displayName;
    private static int lenght;

    public static int Lenght
    {
        get { return lenght; }
        set { lenght = value; }
    }

    vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributoRepository vw_usuarioPerfilAtributoRepository = new vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributoRepository();

    public AtributosInModels(string key) 
    {

        _key = key;

    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            Func<vw_UsuarioPerfilAtributo, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => Perf.NomeAtributo == _key;
            var entity = vw_usuarioPerfilAtributoRepository.GetSingle(expressionPerfil);

            if (entity.Tamanho!=null)
            lenght = entity.Tamanho.Value;

            try { displayName = entity.NomeLabel; }
            catch (Exception) { displayName = null; }
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_key) ? "" : displayName;
        }
    }



    public string _key { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
    [AtributosInModels("NomeUsuario")]
    [MaxLength(AtributosInModels.Lenght)]
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
```

if the code was messy I put full**

Now I want load from database the Lenght,DataType,Permission,DisplayFormat.
But the class of models can`t manipulate variables, I was trying use Static methods

```
[MaxLength(AtributosInModels.Lenght)]
```

Error   5   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

failed.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute argument must be known at compile time. Therefore it has to be a constant value.

Comment: So any advice to use the max Length on MVC4?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are up to and what's the reason of using the attribute - is it for validation? How you want to validate it? Manually or have this validated by a built-in mechanism (e.g. EF Validation). If this is the latter you can use just CustomValidationAttribute and put the dynamic logic here. The thing I don't completely grasp is why NomeUsuario can have different leghts. Note, I am not an MVC expert so may be missing something obvious.

Comment: This is because my system that load all your Information from database, so any things that appear on screen browser is written in the database, even the same models css are working this way for the customer who wants to change anything anytime I made screens with friendly interface and easy(translate,adapt for any bussiness, maintenance). Although it may appear that in String Lenght is a bit useless, it works equally for various other data annotations.